# OpenShift Origin: Getting started Build example : https error on pushing to registry

Tags: openshift-origin

I am trying the learn OpenShift Origin, and was going through the Getting Started example. I did all steps prior to creating a new application that combines a builder image for Node.js. I can see I have configured the docker registry using  oc adm registry.

But in the build logs I see an error as

Pushing image 172.30.134.94:5000/test/nodejs-ex:latest ...
Registry server Address: 
Registry server User Name: serviceaccount
Registry server Email: serviceaccount@example.org
Registry server Password: <>
error: build error: Failed to push image: Get https://172.30.134.94:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

and the build fails.

What could be the possible issue. Is it some port I have not opened or something? I would really appreciate if someone can share some insight on this and on what I may be doing wrong to get things to work

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a fault in the setting up of insecure registries. Fixed it and things started working.